# Xamarin exec logcat command and read results to string

Tags: android, xamarin.android, logcat

Is it possible to exec commands in a Xamarin application? Consider the following:

var process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("logcat");
                var hasExited= await process.WaitForAsync();

I would like to be able to take the results of process and read it to a string. This can be done in native Android, but I am looking for a Xamarin C# solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Android is based on native Android.So you can call this method in Xamarin.Android .

```
var process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("getprop");

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.InputStream));

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
string line;

while ((line = bufferedReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  builder.Append(line + "\n");
}

System.Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```